# SQL Server 2016: Error when selecting from sys.messages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Since roughly one week, after a reboot of my server hardware, I have a strange error when trying to execute the following command:

```
USE master;
SELECT * FROM sys.messages;
```

The error, in german, says the following:

> Fehler beim Laden der Formatzeichenfolge für Fehler "997", Sprachen-ID "1033". Betriebssystemfehler: 317(Das System hat keinen Meldungstext für die Meldungsnummer 0x997 in der Meldungsdatei 1033 gefunden.). Überprüfen Sie, ob die Ressourcendatei mit der ausführbaren Datei von SQL Server übereinstimmt und ob die Ressourcendatei im lokalisierten Verzeichnis mit der Datei im englischen Verzeichnis übereinstimmt. Überprüfen Sie auch die Speicherauslastung.

Roughly translated:

> Error loading the format string for error 997 with the language ID 1033, operating system error 317 (The system could not find a message string for error number 0x997 in message file 1033). Check if the resource file matches with the executable file of SQL server and if the resource file in the localized folder matches the one in the english directory. Check the memory usage.

The memory usage can't be the issue here, there is plenty of both RAM and disk space available.
I checked the resource files in the 1033 folder (this one: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Resources\1033 ), there were no change dates newer than 2016 (and the server has had many reboots since then).

I also replaced those resource files with ones from a fresh installation of the same patch level, where I can do the query without issues but it didn't help us out.

I tried restoring the master database, which also didn't yield any positive result (I restored it to a backup one day before that reboot).

Does anybody have any other ideas about what could be done? I tried searching for articles and issues about this same problem but the only posts I found were many years old and the linked solutions no longer exist.

Comment: FWIW, 997 is `ERROR_IO_PENDING` and 0x997 is `NERR_NetlogonNotStarted` when interpreted as Win32 error codes, though neither may be relevant. The actual error you're getting has SQL error number 18058, and the English version is actually `Failed to load format string for error %d, language id %d. Operating system error: %s. Check that the resource file matches SQL Server executable, and resource file in localized directory matches the file under English directory. Also check memory usage.` in English.

Comment: Meanwhile, SQL error 997 is `Failed to get the update lock on database '%.*ls'.`, and there is no error 0x997 (2455). If the latter is the problem it's hard to see what a solution might be, as there might be stray code in the engine itself invoking a non-existent error code (the range from 2400 - 2500 is conspicuously gappy). There is no message for that code on 2016, 2019 or for that matter 2012. I recommend a hardware check, a `DBCC CHECKDB` of everything and then a complete reinstall/migrating to a new server, as this rabbit hole might go down too deep.